# Looking for national landscape character typology - England

Tags: data

Natural England had created a landscape character type dataset which was available on Magic (https://magic.defra.gov.uk/magicmap.aspx), though it has since been removed - or the licence has. Is this dataset available elsewhere?

I've noticed each council have conducted their own landscape character assessment and have produced landscape character type, was wondering if there is one dataset that covers the entirety of England at all?

Example here: http://landscape-east.org.uk/east-england-landscape-typology

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site. Open-ended data requests are off-topic here. If you're looking for open data, then the SE site better suited for that is [opendata.se].